# How to avoid Uri Class removes special characters from Url

Tags: c#, uri

I am trying to avoid that when Uri class creates a new Uri it automatically removes special http characters like %20

How can I avoid it?

```
imageUrl = https://xxx/authors/Faleria%20Bednaril.jpeg;
result.ImageUrl = new Uri(imageUrl);

//result.ImageUrl = "https://xxx/authors/Faleria Bednaril.jpeg"
```

Comment: Code in the question *does not* demonstrate problem -`(new Uri("https://xxx/authors/Faleria%20Bednaril.jpeg")).AbsoluteUri`

Answer (score 0):

Just call `result.ImageUrl.OriginalString` or `result.ImageUrl.AbsolutePath` if you really need those special characters. The Uri class isn't automatically removing anything.